# Python Arrow datetime function returns a timestamp with seconds field value more than 60

Tags: python, datetime, utc, python-arrow

I have a function in my code for taking a UTC time argument like - `2023-11-06T20:53:39.062Z`, convert it to EST time and then return in a format as 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS'.

```
def date_conv(time):
    est = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Toronto')
    est_time = arrow.get(time).astimezone(est)
    return str(arrow.get(est_time).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS"))
```

However this sometimes returns a time as `16-11-2023 15:11:79`with seconds field > 60, which is not desirable. What is exactly wrong in the code?

Comment: What do you need arrow for in the first place? Standard-lib-only: `datetime.fromisoformat("2023-11-06T20:53:39.062Z").astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/New_York")).strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")`.

Comment: Hi, this I tried this first, but was giving error - Invalid isoformat stringm because my datetime object is string.

Comment: so, did you try to run my code example from the comment? did it work? requires Python 3.11 btw.

Comment: Yes, may be because my python is not 3.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss" for the format.

MM is for month (and you are using it for the minutes) and SS is for subseconds, that's why you get a value greater than 60.

See full docs to know all tokens:
https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#supported-tokens

Comment: Thank you !! I should have read the documentation properly.